# What is this weird error when I compile my source code with android-ndk-10d?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, android-ndk, arm, shared-libraries

This is a project that was worked on a while ago. It used androind-ndk-r7b to compile and android-2.3.7 to test the code. I was given the task to port it to the latest android or atleast 4.4. The source code is one year old, so the last compiler it supports is gcc-4.6 and g++-4.6. Therefore, I used android-ndk-r10d, which is the last revision of android ndk to support the 4.6 compiler. Now I compile some external android libraries, which are compiled without any issue. Then, I compile the source code of my application using ndk. The ndk is supposed to generate a shared library that can be used in my app. The shared library links to the external android libraries which are already compiler. So when the ndk-build script gets to the last step of generating the shared library file, I get this weird error. I have looked alot on the internet and could not find anything related to it. Please, need expert advice.

The error is:

> /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: format 'default' not supported; treating as elf (supported formats: elf, binary)

If you need more info on the problem, let me know. I'll upload more info.

**Update:**

Sorry, I am a newbie to stack overflow. Thanks for keeping up with me. So I get these and many other errors. I think these are standard functions that shouldn't be undefined.

> /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi/thumb/libgnustl_static.a(atexit_arm.o): in function __aeabi_atexit:/s/ndk-toolchain/src/gcc/gcc-4.6/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/atexit_arm.cc:35: error: undefined reference to '__cxa_atexit'
>   /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi/thumb/libgnustl_static.a(eh_globals.o): in function __eh_globals_init::~__eh_globals_init():/tmp/ndk-user/tmp/gnu-libstdc++/static-armeabithumb-4.6/include/arm-linux-androideabi/bits/gthr-default.h:727: error: undefined reference to 'pthread_key_delete'
>   /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi/thumb/libgnustl_static.a(eh_globals.o): in function __cxa_get_globals_fast:/tmp/ndk-user/tmp/gnu-libstdc++/static-armeabithumb-4.6/include/arm-linux-androideabi/bits/gthr-default.h:733: error: undefined reference to 'pthread_getspecific'
>   /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi/thumb/libgnustl_static.a(eh_globals.o): in function __cxa_get_globals:/tmp/ndk-user/tmp/gnu-libstdc++/static-armeabithumb-4.6/include/arm-linux-androideabi/bits/gthr-default.h:733: error: undefined reference to 'pthread_getspecific'
>   /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi/thumb/libgnustl_static.a(eh_globals.o): in function __cxa_get_globals:/tmp/ndk-user/tmp/gnu-libstdc++/static-armeabithumb-4.6/include/arm-linux-androideabi/bits/gthr-default.h:739: error: undefined reference to 'pthread_setspecific'
>   /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi/thumb/libgnustl_static.a(eh_globals.o): in function _GLOBAL__sub_I_eh_globals.cc:/tmp/ndk-user/tmp/gnu-libstdc++/static-armeabithumb-4.6/include/arm-linux-androideabi/bits/gthr-default.h:721: error: undefined reference to 'pthread_key_create'
>   /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi/thumb/libgnustl_static.a(eh_personality.o): in function read_encoded_value_with_base(unsigned char, unsigned int, unsigned char const*, unsigned int*):/s/ndk-toolchain/src/gcc/gcc-4.6/libstdc++-v3/../gcc/unwind-pe.h:257: error: undefined reference to 'abort'
>   /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi/thumb/libgnustl_static.a(eh_personality.o): in function base_of_encoded_value(unsigned char, _Unwind_Context*):/s/ndk-toolchain/src/gcc/gcc-4.6/libstdc++-v3/../gcc/unwind-pe.h:120: error: undefined reference to 'abort'
>   /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi/thumb/libgnustl_static.a(eh_personality.o): in function __gxx_personality_v0:/s/ndk-toolchain/src/gcc/gcc-4.6/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_personality.cc:402: error: undefined reference to 'abort'
>   /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi/thumb/libgnustl_static.a(eh_terminate.o): in function __cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)()):/s/ndk-toolchain/src/gcc/gcc-4.6/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_terminate.cc:41: error: undefined reference to 'abort'
>   /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi/thumb/libgnustl_static.a(guard.o): in function __cxa_guard_acquire:/s/ndk-toolchain/src/gcc/gcc-4.6/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/guard.cc:273: error: undefined reference to 'syscall'
>   /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi/thumb/libgnustl_static.a(guard.o): in function __cxa_guard_abort:/s/ndk-toolchain/src/gcc/gcc-4.6/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/guard.cc:332: error: undefined reference to 'syscall'
>   /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi/thumb/libgnustl_static.a(guard.o): in function __cxa_guard_release:/s/ndk-toolchain/src/gcc/gcc-4.6/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/guard.cc:372: error: undefined reference to 'syscall'
>   /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi/thumb/libgnustl_static.a(pure.o): in function __cxa_pure_virtual:/s/ndk-toolchain/src/gcc/gcc-4.6/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/pure.cc:49: error: undefined reference to 'write'
>   /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi/thumb/libgnustl_static.a(locale_init.o): in function std::locale::_S_initialize():/tmp/ndk-user/tmp/gnu-libstdc++/static-armeabithumb-4.6/include/arm-linux-androideabi/bits/gthr-default.h:713: error: undefined reference to 'pthread_once'
>   /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi/thumb/libgnustl_static.a(locale_init.o): in function std::locale::global(std::locale const&):/s/ndk-toolchain/src/gcc/gcc-4.6/libstdc++-v3/src/locale_init.cc:246: error: undefined reference to 'setlocale'
>   /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi/thumb/libgnustl_static.a(codecvt_members.o): in function std::codecvt::do_out(mbstate_t&, wchar_t const*, wchar_t const*, wchar_t const*&, char*, char*, char*&) const:codecvt_members.cc:81: error: undefined reference to 'wcrtomb'
>   /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi/thumb/libgnustl_static.a(codecvt_members.o): in function std::codecvt::do_out(mbstate_t&, wchar_t const*, wchar_t const*, wchar_t const*&, char*, char*, char*&) const:codecvt_members.cc:66: error: undefined reference to 'wcrtomb'
>   /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi/thumb/libgnustl_static.a(codecvt_members.o): in function std::codecvt::do_in(mbstate_t&, char const*, char const*, char const*&, wchar_t*, wchar_t*, wchar_t*&) const:codecvt_members.cc:126: error: undefined reference to 'mbrtowc'
>   /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi/thumb/libgnustl_static.a(codecvt_members.o): in function std::codecvt::do_length(mbstate_t&, char const*, char const*, unsigned int) const:codecvt_members.cc:191: error: undefined reference to 'mbrtowc'
>   /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi/thumb/libgnustl_static.a(collate_members.o): in function std::collate::_M_compare(char const*, char const*) const:collate_members.cc:46: error: undefined reference to 'strcoll'
>   /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi/thumb/libgnustl_static.a(collate_members.o): in function std::collate::_M_transform(char*, char const*, unsigned int) const:collate_members.cc:54: error: undefined reference to 'strxfrm'
>   /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi/thumb/libgnustl_static.a(collate_members.o): in function std::collate::_M_compare(wchar_t const*, wchar_t const*) const:collate_members.cc:62: error: undefined reference to 'wcscoll'
>   /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi/thumb/libgnustl_static.a(collate_members.o): in function std::collate::_M_transform(wchar_t*, wchar_t const*, unsigned int) const:collate_members.cc:70: error: undefined reference to 'wcsxfrm'
>   /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi/thumb/libgnustl_static.a(ctype_members.o): in function std::ctype::_M_convert_to_wmask(char) const:ctype_members.cc:91: error: undefined reference to 'wctype'
>   /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi/thumb/libgnustl_static.a(ctype_members.o): in function std::ctype::_M_convert_to_wmask(char) const:ctype_members.cc:94: error: undefined reference to 'wctype'
>   /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi/thumb/libgnustl_static.a(ctype_members.o): in function std::ctype::_M_convert_to_wmask(char) const:ctype_members.cc:76: error: undefined reference to 'wctype'
>   /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi/thumb/libgnustl_static.a(ctype_members.o): in function std::ctype::_M_convert_to_wmask(char) const:ctype_members.cc:67: error: undefined reference to 'wctype'
>   /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi/thumb/libgnustl_static.a(ctype_members.o): in function std::ctype::do_toupper(wchar_t) const:ctype_members.cc:104: error: undefined reference to 'towupper'
>   /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi/thumb/libgnustl_static.a(ctype_members.o): in function std::ctype::do_toupper(wchar_t*, wchar_t const*) const:ctype_members.cc:111: error: undefined reference to 'towupper'
>   /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi/thumb/libgnustl_static.a(ctype_members.o): in function std::ctype::do_tolower(wchar_t) const:ctype_members.cc:119: error: undefined reference to 'towlower'
>   /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi/thumb/libgnustl_static.a(ctype_members.o): in function std::ctype::do_tolower(wchar_t*, wchar_t const*) const:ctype_members.cc:126: error: undefined reference to 'towlower'
>   /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi/thumb/libgnustl_static.a(ctype_members.o): in function std::ctype::do_is(char, wchar_t) const:ctype_members.cc:142: error: undefined reference to 'iswctype'
>   /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi/thumb/libgnustl_static.a(ctype_members.o): in function std::ctype::do_is(wchar_t const*, wchar_t const*, char*) const:ctype_members.cc:161: error: undefined reference to 'iswctype'
>   /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi/thumb/libgnustl_static.a(ctype_members.o): in function std::ctype::do_narrow(wchar_t, char) const:ctype_members.cc:210: error: undefined reference to 'wctob'
>   /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi/thumb/libgnustl_static.a(ctype_members.o): in function std::ctype::do_narrow(wchar_t const*, wchar_t const*, char, char*) const:ctype_members.cc:235: error: undefined reference to 'wctob'
>   /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi/thumb/libgnustl_static.a(ctype_members.o): in function std::ctype::do_narrow(wchar_t const*, wchar_t const*, char, char*) const:ctype_members.cc:226: error: undefined reference to 'wctob'
>   /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi/thumb/libgnustl_static.a(ctype_members.o): in function std::ctype::_M_initialize_ctype():ctype_members.cc:249: error: undefined reference to 'wctob'
>   /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi/thumb/libgnustl_static.a(ctype_members.o): in function std::ctype::_M_initialize_ctype():ctype_members.cc:261: error: undefined reference to 'btowc'
>   /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi/thumb/libgnustl_static.a(time_members.o): in function std::__timepunct::_M_put(char*, unsigned int, char const*, tm const*) const:time_members.cc:56: error: undefined reference to 'strftime'
>   /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi/thumb/libgnustl_static.a(time_members.o): in function std::__timepunct::_M_put(wchar_t*, unsigned int, wchar_t const*, tm const*) const:time_members.cc:145: error: undefined reference to 'wcsftime'
>   /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi/thumb/libgnustl_static.a(time_members.o): in function std::__timepunct::_M_put(wchar_t*, unsigned int, wchar_t const*, tm const*) const:time_members.cc:145: error: undefined reference to 'wcsftime'
>   /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi/thumb/libgnustl_static.a(vterminate.o): in function __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler():/s/ndk-toolchain/src/gcc/gcc-4.6/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/vterminate.cc:71: error: undefined reference to 'fputs'
>   /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi/thumb/libgnustl_static.a(vterminate.o): in function __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler():/s/ndk-toolchain/src/gcc/gcc-4.6/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/vterminate.cc:87: error: undefined reference to 'fputc'
>   /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /home/zeeshan/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/thumb/libgcc.a(_dvmd_lnx.o): in function __aeabi_idiv0:/s/ndk-toolchain/src/build/../gcc/gcc-4.6/libgcc/../gcc/config/arm/lib1funcs.asm:1270: error: undefined reference to 'raise'

Comment: Please run your `ndk-build` with **`V=1`** argument, and post the command line that caused the error message.

Comment: Looks like a problem with your makefile. Check the linker option (ld_flags) for a string 'default'. Paste it here and a solution can be arrived at.

Comment: @ArunValiaparambil So running it in verbose mode helped. I found the line that was causing the error. But this only revealed further errors.
One of the errors:

Comment: "previous definition here" assumes that there are few more valuable lines above this error message. Please post full output of the **ld** command. It is also important to include the command line itself, unless you want to find the problem all by yourself.